# Extract a web document using c#

Tags: c#, browser, html, dom

I am trying to get data from a web page using c#

So far this is my code:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

wb.Url = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com");
HtmlDocument doc = wb.Document;

MessageBox.Show(doc.ToString());
```

Unfortunately wb remains null and the Url property never gets set.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I would use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) class instead of the web browser.  The web browser class is more for interaction with a UI, whilst the WebClient is more geared towards programmatic interaction with page.  Here is some example code:

```
private void sendMessage(JaxtrSmsMessage message)
{
    HttpWebRequest request;
    HttpWebResponse response;
    CookieContainer cookies;
    string url = "http://www.jaxtr.com/user/login.jsp";

    try
    {
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(reader.ReadLine());
            }

            //Get the hidden value out of the form.                
            String fp = Regex.Match(sb.ToString(), "\"__fp\"\\svalue=\"(([A-Za-z0-9+/=]){4}){1,19}\"", RegexOptions.None).Value;
            fp = fp.Substring(14);
            fp = fp.Replace("\"", String.Empty);


            cookies = request.CookieContainer;
            //response.Close();
            String requestString = "http://www.jaxtr.com/user/Login.action?tzOffset=6&navigateURL=&refPage=&jaxtrId=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(credentials.Username) + "&password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(credentials.Password) + "&Login=Login&_sourcePage=%2Flogin.jsp&__fp="+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fp);
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestString);
            request.CookieContainer = cookies; //added by myself

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Response from login:" + response.StatusCode);

            String messageText = (message.TruncateMessage && message.MessageText.Length > JaxtrSmsMessage.MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH ? message.MessageText.Substring(JaxtrSmsMessage.MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) : message.MessageText);

            String messageURL = "http://www.jaxtr.com/user/sendsms?CountryName=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message.CountryName) + "&phone=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message.DestinationPhoneNumber) + "&message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(messageText) + "&bySMS=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message.BySMS.ToString().ToLower());

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(messageURL);
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Response from send SMS command=" + response.StatusCode);

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    output.AppendLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client was unable to connect!");
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        throw new SMSDeliveryException("Unable to deliver SMS message because "+e.Message, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to call navigate method with URL path and you have to trap Document complete event from the web browser control

```
 webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
 webBrowser.Navigate("http:\\www.microsoft.com");
```

and then use document complete event to get the loaded web page document

```
 void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {             
          MessageBox.Show(webBrowser.DocumentText.ToString());
    }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

i think  you're forgetting to initiate the navigation to the page. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate.aspx)

But also...

Navigation is an async process. You need to put the web browser object at class scope and then handle the navigated event like this:

```
    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    }
```

You'll see that doc will be non null in the handler.

Comment: nope :/ i added that before the wb.Url part and still no progress :/

Comment: i added some more info. i used it in my local test prj. It'll solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try the `DocumentText` property of the `HtmlDocument`, rather than calling `ToString()`.